# When to use a reference parameter in C++ function design

Tags: c++

I have a simple question. In my computer class I was told a reference parameter is used when you want to modify the original input and store it in the reference memory for future access. You attach an & to the end of the variable to do this, for example for the function: void firstName(string name)

However, I am reviewing a program from my lab tutor in which you input your first and last name, for example John Smith and it outputs as Smith, John.

In this case as you are inputting John Smith it would seem to be that the following void function should not use a reference parameter but just a regular one, void readName(string name)

Except it does not, it uses a reference parameter: it is set as void readName(string& name)

Why does one use a reference parameter in this case? In my opinion it is just extracting the name and then doing a cout on it? I can't see where the modification of the string is occurring to justify it being a reference parameter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much..

```
//
// This program reads the first name and last name of a student,
// and prints it as last name, first name
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
void readName(string&);
void extract(string, string&, string&);
void printName(string, string);

// Constant declarations

int main()
{
  string name, firstName, lastName;

  char response;

  do {

    readName(name);
    extract(name, firstName, lastName);
    printName(firstName, lastName);

    cout << "Try again (Y/N)? ";
    cin >> response;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

  } while (tolower(response) == 'y');

  return 0;
}

// Function definitions

// Purpose: gets the student's name from a user
// Parameters: Inputs --
//             Outputs -- name -- string
//             Inputs/Outputs --
// Returns:
void readName(string& name){
  cout << "Enter student's first name and last name -- ";
  getline(cin, name);
}

// Purpose: extracts firstName and lastName
// Parameters: Inputs -- name is string
//             Outputs -- firstName and lastName are string
//             Inputs/Outputs --
// Returns:
void extract(string name, string& firstName, string& lastName){

  firstName = "";
  lastName = "";
  string::size_type i;
  for (i = 0; !isspace(name.at(i)); i++)
    firstName = firstName + name.at(i);

  for (i = i + 1; i < name.length(); i++)
      lastName = lastName + name[i];
}

// Purpose: prints firstName and lastName in the form of lastName, firstName
// Parameters: Inputs -- firstName and lastName are string
//             Outputs --
//             Inputs/Outputs --
// Returns:
void printName(string firstName, string lastName){
  cout << lastName << ", " << firstName << endl;
}
```

expected void readName(string name) to work in this program but it does not. void readName(string& name) is the only syntax that works for perform the desired function.

Comment: "*In my opinion it is just extracting the name and then doing a cout on it?*" How do you figure? `readName` is just reading the name. That requires writing the name somewhere that subsequent code can see it. "*I can't see where the modification of the string is occurring to justify it being a reference parameter.*" It's the part where `readName` *reads the name*.

Comment: Reference parameters aside (your instructor may be using them for teaching purposes), I'd prefer `std::string readName()` without any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case as you are inputting John Smith it would seem to be that the
> following void function should not use a reference parameter but just a
> regular one, `void readName(string name)`

And then after "inputting John Smith" into this `name`, this `name` will be "John Smith", but the original parameter that gets passed in:

> readName(name);

This particular `name` remains unaffected. If it's still the original, default, empty string, it's still just as empty as it's ever been before.

The `name` in the `main()`, and this `name` parameter in `readName()` have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with each other. They are two completely different objects, that just by accident happen to have the same name.

Passing the `name` from `main` into a `void readName(string name)` creates a copy of `main`'s `name`, and this copied object becomes `readName`'s name. That's how passing parameters by value (as opposed by reference) means, in C++.

Feel free to "inputting" anything you want, into this `name`. It won't make a bit of a difference to `main`'s original `name`.

> Except it does not, it uses a reference parameter: it is set as void
> readName(string& name)

And now, after "inputting John Smith" into this `name`, guess what happens to `main`'s original `name`. Just take a wild guess. Take your best shot.

Well, what do you know: your guess was right. This ends up "inputting John Smith" into `main`'s actual `name` object. Because it gets passed "by reference". That's what "by reference" means, in C++. It refers to the original object that gets passed in.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this to me Sam. I thought this might have been happening, (the 'name' in the readName function and main function were not same) but I couldn't put it together logically. The post put my thoughts together for me. Have a great day.